# Not getting lines - std::getline

Tags: c++

I posted this question a couple of days back and i just have another question, I have it outputting the first line of the data but it inst outputting the rest of the lines kinda stumped.

```
ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("Data.txt");
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Wip" << std::endl;

    ifstream myReadFile;
     myReadFile.open("Data.txt");
     std::string output;
     std::getline(myReadFile, output);
     std::cout << output << "\n";
     myReadFile.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
```

sample data

```
Name: jobes lobes
Age: 89
Address: 9 neuern_st mucgregor brosbane australia
```

Comment: Well, you're only reading the first line. You want to do a `while` loop that reads the file until EOF is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a while loop so you can extract continuously. Extraction will finish when the stream fails to extract:

```
while (std::getline(myReadFile, output))
{
    std::cout << output << "\n";
}
```